# Elasticsearch 6.6 with Magento 2.3 and Nginx, need a proxy?

Tags: magento2, nginx, elasticsearch, proxy

I am installing Elasticsearch 6.6 on my system (Ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx 1.14) and to configure Elasticsearch and Nginx, I find in the official documentation the following section:

[Configure nginx and Elasticsearch](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-config-nginx.html)

[image]

**Is it necessary to set a proxy on my Nginx so that Elasticsearch works with Magento 2 correctly?**

Thank you in advance